# Compare values in two tables and create a list in Django

Tags: django

I have two models. I need to pull out the employeeno data from Model1 that is not present in Model2. How to do this?

**Model1**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employeeno = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=False)
    days = models.IntegerField('Number of Days', null=False)
```

**Model2**

```
class RemEmployee(models.Model):
    employeeno = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=False, unique=True)
    reason= models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can Understand from you Data models, is that You want to Get those **Employee Objects which are not present as Foreign key in RemEmployee Table**.

So, you can find this by **following query**

```
Employee.objects.filter(rememployee__isnull=True).values_list('employeeno', flat=True)
```

Note: Although you have made Foreign key as unique in RemEmployee which makes it a OneToOne key(Not related to question but just telling)

Comment: Thanks Sahil. This solved the problem. But, just out of curiosity, how to handle the same problem if the selected models are Model2 and Model3 (not defined here. lets assume it looks similar to Model2)?

Comment: Couldn't understand,, Please explain a bit, I understood that Model3 also has a foreign key like Model2 to Model1. What do you want to query using Model2 and Model3 ?

Comment: Need to pull out the employeeno data from Model2 that is not present in Model3. Here, employeeno entry is a Foreign Key in Model2 and Model3.

Comment: you can try this: (Have not Tested)
RemEmployee.objects.filter(employeeno__model3__isnull=True).distinct().values_list('employeeno__employeeno', flat=True)

Answer (score 1):

```
Employee.objects.exclude(employeeno__in=RemEmployee.objects.values_list('employeeno', flat=True))
```

This will return all `Employee` objects whose `employeeno` isn't shared by any `RemEmployee` objects.

Comment: I am getting this error:
    operator does not exist: character varying = integer
    LINE 1: ...NOT ("employee_creator_employeeno"."employeeno" IN (SELECT...
    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.